# Multiple AnimationDrawables at the same time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animationdrawable

Is it possible to generate 2 animationdrawables at the same time?

I tried it with threads:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        { 
animation1.start(); 
 }   

}};
Thread t2 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        { 
animation2.start(); 
 }   
}};

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

This doesn't work.
I load the resources for the animation from a xml-file.

Comment: Is this code located in OnCreate method or not??

Comment: yes it is.and I think it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your code in onCreate() method and yes, it's wrong. If you check javaDoc for animationDrawable method start(), you will see you can't start in `onCreate()`, but you should call it in `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` method.